# PyMC3 - Poisson works with switch point, Exponential does not

Tags: python, pymc, pymc3

The following model (taken from the Bayesian Methods for Hackers) works with the Poisson.

```
count_data = np.loadtxt("data/txtdata.csv")
n_count_data = len(count_data) 

with pm.Model() as model:
alpha = 1.0/count_data.mean()  # Recall count_data is the
                               # variable that holds our txt counts
lambda_1 = pm.Exponential("lambda_1", alpha)
lambda_2 = pm.Exponential("lambda_2", alpha)

tau = pm.DiscreteUniform("tau", lower=0, upper=n_count_data - 1)

idx = np.arange(n_count_data) # Index
lambda_ = pm.math.switch(tau >= idx, lambda_1,lambda_2)

observation = pm.Poisson("obs", lambda_, observed=count_data)

step = [pm.Metropolis(), pm.NUTS()]
trace = pm.sample(10000, tune=5000,step=step)
pm.traceplot(trace, ['lambda_1', 'lambda_2', 'tau'])
plt.show()
```

**With Poisson Distribution :**

[image: With Poisson Distribution]

However, when using an Exponential random variable in this model:

```
observation = pm.Exponential("obs", lambda_, observed=count_data)
```

I get:

**With Exponential Distribution :**
[image: With Exponential Distribution]

The reason I wish to use Exponential distribution is using non integers.

I am not sure if the problem is with the lambda_ definition or with something else (the sampler needed for this).

Answer (score 1):

The Poisson distribution models counts.

It can also used in things like queue networks to model the inter-arrival times of single customers. Note, the expected inter-arrival times of customers would be the inverse of the rate parameter (usually lambda).

One can feed data to the Poisson process as counts per fixed sampled interval of time e.g. how many customers did you get per day.

An exponential distribution is used to model some transition time. It is not a count process. It is a continuous process with its discrete analog being the geometric distribution.

A Poisson distribution is used to model discrete data and discrete counts that have exponential distribution of time between successive counts.

They are very similar looking but are different in nature.

It is likely that the count data that was fed into the exponential distribution confused the whole process.

In other words, the exponential distribution is not the appropriate model as it can not understand the given data.